# How do you change the parameter description in StrongLoop?

Tags: api, loopbackjs, strongloop

Building our first API in StrongLoop.  By default our id parameters all show up as "Model id" or "PersistedModel Id".  (See example in screenshot)

I would like to replace these with something more meaningful to the API users, but can't figure out where this is done.

[image: Screenshot from Strongloop Explorer showing Delete endpoint]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no elegant way to overwrite description of built-in API methods, I created [a simple model mixin](https://github.com/touhonoob/loopback-method-description-mixin) which can achieve your requirement.

Please follow [the documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+mixins#Definingmixins-Referencemixinsinmodel-config.js) to integrate the mixin into your project.

For custom API methods, please read [remoteMethods](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods#Remotemethods-Options). It's very easy to define your own description for them.

[image: demo for mixin]